# Maven Install Failure on Flex project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-flex

I am getting below error

```
[ERROR] Flex compiler error (C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\datavisualization\4.1.0.16248\datavisualization-4.1.0.16248.swc$defaults.css at 13:-1)
[ERROR] { expected.
[ERROR] Flex compiler error (C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\datavisualization\4.1.0.16248\datavisualization-4.1.0.16248.swc$defaults.css at 14:-1)
[ERROR] { expected.
[ERROR] Flex compiler error (C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\datavisualization\4.1.0.16248\datavisualization-4.1.0.16248.swc$defaults.css at 181:-1)
[ERROR] Unexpected character: D.
[ERROR] Flex compiler error (C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\datavisualization\4.1.0.16248\datavisualization-4.1.0.16248.swc$defaults.css at 185:-1)
[ERROR] { expected.
[ERROR] Flex compiler error (C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\framework\4.1.0.16248\framework-4.1.0.16248.swc$defaults.css at 15:-1)
[ERROR] { expected.
[ERROR] Flex compiler error (C:\Users\Iotasol Inc\.m2\repository\com\adobe\flex\framework\spark\4.1.0.16248\spark-4.1.0.16248.swc$defaults.css at 15:-1)
[ERROR] { expected.
```

When i try to run maven install on my project, below is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-note</artifactId>
    <version>1.31</version>
    <name>test-note</name>

    <packaging>swf</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
         <id>servebox</id>
         <url>http://maven.servebox.org/repository/</url>
        </repository>           
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>flexmojos-repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
            <id>servebox</id>
            <name>ServeBox Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.servebox.org/repository</url>
        </pluginRepository>     
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <!-- <version>4.0-RC2</version> -->
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <locales>
                        <locale>en_US</locale>
                    </locales>
                     <keepAs3Metadatas>  
                       <name>Autowired</name>  
                     </keepAs3Metadatas>  
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.servebox.flex</groupId>
                <artifactId>flex-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flexunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flash.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.sdkcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.sdkcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>flex</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.sdkcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.sdkcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>utilities</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOCALE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.locales.en_US</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework_rb</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.locales.en_US</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpc_rb</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-actionscript</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.flexlib</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexlib</artifactId>
            <version>2.6-M1</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>          

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anybody help on why this error is coming and how to fix it

Comment: Try deleting the `com\adobe\flex\framework\datavisualization\` directory from repository and re-run mvn install

Comment: thanks for reply @keerthivasan, but it has not helped

Comment: Hi, I would strongly suggest to go to one of the more recent flexmjos versions. Use 6.0.1 if you are using an adobe FDK or 7.0.1 if you are intending on using Apache Flex. 3.2.0 and 4.0-RC2 are both years old and a lot has been done since then.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I am having a similar issue